# How to filter in C# LINQ only one string

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

I have this code:

```
            var result = _Repository.Get()
            .Skip(query.Skip)
            .Take(query.Top)
            .Where(x => 
                  (x.disabled == false)
            )
            .Select(x => new {
                x.Id,
                x.Text,
                x.Date
            });
            return result;
    }
```

The query items are passed by URL to the service and I like to filter by query.Filter, this is a string only one string, no array

What is the procedure to filter?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean .Where()?

Comment: Do you mean by usin Where?

Comment: Edited, where added in query (I only copy the most important)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want. you say "I like to filter by query.Filter" but you haven't indicated what should be filtered by that.

Comment: @user3145838: Do you mean, you are getting filter parameters as a part of `queryString(URL i.e. http://example.com?x=1&y=2&z=3)`. Now you want to apply these filters i.e. x = 1, y=2, z= 3. You Query variable holds `http://example.com?x=1&y=2&z=3`, Is that correct?

Comment: ((query.Filter != null) && (x.Text.Contains(query.Filter)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand the result is a collection so you could filter it.

```
 var result = _Repository.Get()
                .Skip(query.Skip)
                .Take(query.Top)
                .Where(x => 
                      x.disabled == false &&
                      x.FilterField == query.Filter)
                )
                .Select(x => new {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Text,
                    x.Date
                });
                return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var result = _Repository.Get()
        .Skip(query.Skip)
        .Take(query.Top)
        .Where(x => 
              (x.disabled == false && x.Text == query.Filter)
        )
        .Select(x => new {
            x.Id,
            x.Text,
            x.Date
        });
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you meant you want to express that in the Where clause like:

```
 var result = _Repository.Get()
        .Skip(query.Skip)
        .Take(query.Top)
        .Where(el => !el.disabled && el.FieldToMatch == query.Filter)
        .Select(x => new {
            x.Id,
            x.Text,
            x.Date
        });

 return result;
```

Comment: But you don't filter in this query, I like to filter with the string query.Filter

Comment: You are saying that query.Filter is a string and you want to filter the collection by this string, what should this string match within this collection?